# Law of Cosines Proof

Tags: trigonometry

This question is based on the diagram

[image]

taken from this [link](http://www.ies.co.jp/math/products/trig/applets/yogen_auto/yogen_auto.html). I don't understand why the areas of A6 and A5 adds up to $2bc\cos(A)$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines#Proofs

Comment: Few days ago I noticed this discussion:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/132/stop-tagging-things-with-the-tag-proofs

Comment: Here's my version of that diagram: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803/what-is-the-most-elegant-proof-of-the-pythagorean-theorem/1336#1336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at A5. It is a rectangle with side $b$ and, say, $x$.
Now $\cos A= x/c$, so $x=c\cos A$. Hence the area of A5 is $bx=bc\cos A$.

A similar argument tells you that the area of A6 is $cb\cos A$.

Answer (score 1):

The other side of A6 has length $c \cos A$ and that of A5 length $b \cos A.$

So their total area is $b \times c \cos A + c \times b \cos A = 2bc \cos A.$