# Have you come across this proof of the Pythagoras Theorem?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I have come across many proofs of Pythagoras theorem like these -
[image]

But today when i was trying different methods of proving the pythagorean theorem i found a way to prove it. But the construction is so simple and obvious so I wanted to check if this proof is there somewhere -
[image]

Consider this right triangle with $\angle B = 90°$

$\Rightarrow △ABC \sim  △ADB \Rightarrow \dfrac{AB}{AD}=\dfrac{AC}{AB} \Rightarrow AB^2=AC.AD \cdots (I)$

Similarly ,

$△ABC \sim △BDC \Rightarrow \dfrac{BC}{DC}=\dfrac{AC}{BC} \Rightarrow BC^2=AC.DC \cdots (II)$

Adding $(I) , (II) \Rightarrow AB^2+BC^2=AC(AD+DC)=AC^2$. Hence Proved.

A proof so simple yet I never came across it...

Comment: This site has $100$ different proofs for Pythagoras. Did you look for your proof there? Here is a link to start: [Pythagoras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803/what-is-the-most-elegant-proof-of-the-pythagorean-theorem), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540415/what-is-the-simplest-proof-of-the-pythagorean-theorem-you-know?noredirect=1&lq=1). Then check the linked posts at the right side.

Comment: Yes I checked many posts related to pythagoras theorem on this website. Completing the square was the most common proof.

Comment: I, at the risk of sounding overly rude, would like to inform you that we, in grade 10, were made to study this proof as a STANDARD PROOF OF PYTHAGORAS’ THEOREM and had to reproduce it in multiple exams. You can check out pages 145-146 [here](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/jemh106.pdf). This proof was [purportedly discovered by Einstein](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/on-einsteins-proof-of-the-so-called-pythagorean-theorem)(yes, Mr. Albert Einstein of General Relativity fame himself). So you seem to be discovering the same things as him;)…