# How to derive the law of cosines without the pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

To me, it seems that the Pythagorean theorem is a special case of the law of cosines. However, all derivations that I can find seem to use the Pythagorean theorem in the derivation. Are there any simple (preferably geometric) derivations of the law of cosines that *don't* reference the Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: I think any proof of Pythagoras theorem can be adapted to get the law of cosines.

Comment: You might have already looked at this. But wiki has some nice collections including a proof comparing the areas of a heptagon. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines#By_comparing_areas)

Comment: See my answer to "What is the most elegant proof of the Pythagorean Theorem?" : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1336/409

Comment: Beautiful. Could you post it here so I can credit the answer?

Comment: The law of cosines and Pythagoras theorem are equivalent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[As requested, posting a comment as a full answer.]

Taken from [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1336/409) to the question ["What is the most elegant proof of the Pythagorean Theorem?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803/409) ...

[image: Law of Cosines Picture Proof]

Comment: What's fun is if C is in fact a right angle, the blue rectangles shrink to nothing, and you're left with Euclid's proof of Pythagoras. He was so close to proving it all in one go!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing comes to mind. There are a few ways of saying that the Law of Cosines as you know it demands the Pythagorean Theorem. Your questions appear to be about simplifying mathematics, as mentioned on your website. It turns out that there is always an irreducible minimum that needs to be taken more or less on faith. In the setting of plane geometry, one of these items is the Parallel Postulate. With that and the other axiomatic items, the Law of Cosines is true.

On the other hand, if you prefer to deny the parallel postulate, you get the hyperbolic plane (actually there is a constant involved) where there are two unfamiliar Laws of Cosines, because similar triangles are always congruent. Not my fault, I just work there.

I suggest you get *Geometry: Euclid and Beyond* by Hartshorne and *Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries*, 4th edition, by Greenberg.

Comment: I don't buy it. The Pythagorean Theorem is a special case of the law of cosines. I won't believe that there's not a proof of the latter (independent of the former) until I see a proof that it can't be done.

Comment: Alright. I will leave this here, although there is an answer now that seems to be what you actually wanted.