# How do squares of non-right triangles relate?

Tags: geometry, triangles

How do squares of the sides of a triangle, any triangle, relate?

Comment: It will be great if you draw the two areas $ a \cdot b \cdot \sin C_1$ where $C_1$is the complement.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/147692/409).

Comment: So fine, and  convincing... The portions around orthocenter simply disappear for the Pythagoras case..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general rule that relates the sides of a triangle is called the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). It regards the following situation, where you know an angle of the triangle and want to relate the side lengths: [image]

It is stated as follows:
$$C^2=A^2+B^2-2AB\cos(\alpha).$$
Note that this has a very similar form to the Pythagorean theorem - just with an extra adjustment for the angle $\alpha$. In particular, if $\alpha$ is a right angle, this last term is zero, so it reduces to the Pythagorean theorem. The equation also tells us that when $\alpha$ is obtuse, the opposite is longer than it would be in a right triangle and when $\alpha$ is acute, the opposite side is shorter.

Comment: Often opposite side-angle pairs are given "related" symbols, for example if one side/angle is called $A$, then the opposite angle/side is called $\alpha$, $a$ or similar (example: [Wikipedia, Solution of triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles)). However, you did not follow that practice (in your formula, $\alpha$ and $A$ must be adjacent). Just saying, so that people who are used to such a convention, will not get confused.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the short answer.

Cosine Rule, whose special case is the Pythagoras theorem.

$$ c^2= a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b \cos C$$

when $C = 90^0. $