# curiosity in circular analytical geometry

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

**Curiosity**

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a circle of radius $r$, centered at the origin.

Assign point $O$ the cartesian coordinate $(0,0).$

Let $k$ be a **fixed** element in $(0,r).$

Set points A and B to have cartesian coordinates $(0,k)$ and $(0,-k)$ respectively.

Choose point C at random on $\mathscr{C}.\;$ Then $\;\left|\;\overline{OC}\;\right|^2 = r^2.$

The end of this query gives an **Algebraic Demonstration** that 
regardless of the point $C$ chosen, 
$\;\left|\;\overline{AC}\;\right|^2 + \left|\;\overline{BC}\;\right|^2 = 2(r^2 + k^2).$

**Questions**

Question 1 below added, per Blue's suggestion.

1. see this query's **Background** section (the next section).  My underlying desire is to find a **non-algebraic** way of predicting that 
    given $\;z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}\;$ the Locus of $\;\{z\; :\; 
   |z-z_1|^2 + |z-z_2|^2 \;=\;$ a constant$\}\;$ **will be a circle.**  I have accepted Blue's answer, re Appollonious' (**triangle-oriented**) theorem, which does facilitate the prediction, though the logic is *convoluted.*  I **would welcome** a separate **circle-oriented** geometry theorem that **more directly** facilitates the prediction.

The remaining questions in this section are now somewhat redundant, but are left in as a reference to how I originally posed my questions.

2. Can this result be demonstrated **geometrically, without resorting to algebra**?
3. Does this result have a (theorem) name?
4. Is there a **free online geometry resource (e.g. pdf)** that includes this result?

**Background**

In "An Introduction to Complex Function Theory", Bruce Palka, 1991, problem
4.6.vii, p.26 specifies:
geometrically describe $\;\{z\;:\;\left|z-i\right|^2 + \left|z+i\right|^2 = 4\}.\;$
After determining that the Locus was a circle of radius 1, centered at the origin,
I realized that 
if the right hand side $\; = R \;: \;R>2\;$ then the Locus is a circle of radius 
$\;\sqrt{(R-2)/2}.$
My (brief) subsequent online research found no mention of this **curious** result.

**Algebraic Demonstration**

In the diagram at the end of this query, 
$\;\mathscr{C}, r, k,\;$ point $A$ and point $B$ are as described
in the **Curiousity** section, at the start of this query.

Randomly choose $t$ in $\;(k, r)\;$ and assign point $D$ the cartesian coordinates
$(0,t).$

Let point $C_1$ represent the right-hand-side intersection of $\;\mathscr{C}\;$
with the line $\;y=t.$

Similarly, randomly choose $s$ in $\;(0,k),\;$ and assign point $E$ the cartesian 
coordinate $\;(0,s).$

Similarly, let point $C_2$ represent the left-hand-side intersection of $\;\mathscr{C}\;$
with the line $\;y=s.$

$\left|\;\overline{DC_1}\;\right|^2 \;= \;r^2 - t^2.$ 
$\left|\;\overline{AC_1}\;\right|^2 \;= \;(t-k)^2 
+ \left|\;\overline{DC_1}\;\right|^2.$ 
$\left|\;\overline{BC_1}\;\right|^2 \;= \;(t+k)^2 
+ \left|\;\overline{DC_1}\;\right|^2.$ 
$\left|\;\overline{AC_1}\;\right|^2
+ \left|\;\overline{BC_1}\;\right|^2 
\;= \;2(t^2 + k^2) \;+ \;2(r^2 - t^2) \;= \;2(r^2 + k^2).$

$\left|\;\overline{EC_2}\;\right|^2 \;= \;r^2 - s^2.$ 
$\left|\;\overline{AC_2}\;\right|^2 \;= \;(k-s)^2 
+ \left|\;\overline{EC_2}\;\right|^2.$ 
$\left|\;\overline{BC_2}\;\right|^2 \;= \;(k+s)^2 
+ \left|\;\overline{EC_2}\;\right|^2.$ 
$\left|\;\overline{AC_2}\;\right|^2
+ \left|\;\overline{BC_2}\;\right|^2 
\;= \;2(k^2 + s^2) \;+ \;2(r^2 - s^2) \;= \;2(r^2 + k^2).$

[image]

Comment: This can be considered simple application of the Law of Cosines and the fact that supplementary angles have negative cosines. $$\begin{align}0 &= 2kr (\cos\angle COA+\cos\angle COB) \\ &= (|AC|^2-k^2-r^2)+(|BC|^2-k^2-r^2) \\ &=|AC|^2+|BC|^2-2(k^2+r^2)\end{align}$$ (I don't know if you'd consider this too "algebraic".) I'm not aware of any name for this result; it doesn't seem to need one.

Comment: By the way, [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2483937/409) gives a geometric derivation of the Law of Cosines.

Comment: @Blue slick...(but still algebraic).  I am actually surprised that my result isn't less obscure.

Comment: I'll note that the result has nothing to do with a circle; rather, it's simply a triangle relation. In particular, it relates the length of a median to other segments in a triangle. In that regard, it's a special case of [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem). (Ah! As the Wikipedia entry notes, the median case *does* have a name: [Apollonius's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative (but still very "algebraic") derivation that leverages [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem) (*the angle inscribed in a semicircle is right*):

[image]

$$\begin{align}
a^2+b^2 
&= \left(m^2+p^2\right)+\left(n^2+q^2\right) \\
&=\left(m^2+n^2\right)+\left(p^2+q^2\right) \\
&=\left(r+k\right)^2+\left(r-k\right)^2 \\
&=2\left(r^2+k^2\right)
\end{align}$$

---

This result, which relates the length of a median to other segments in $\triangle ABC$, is [Apollonius's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem). It's a special case of [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) for the length of an arbitrary cevian.

Comment: unfortunately, I have to accept your answer as on-point.  However, examine my question from the point of view of **background.**  The idea is that given $\;z_1, z_2 \in\mathbb{C}\;$, it is desired to predict **in advance** (without algebra) that the Locus of $\;\{z\;:|z-z_1|^2 + |z-z_2|^2 = \;$a constant$\}\;$ will be a circle.  It takes some *convoluted* logic to use Appollonius' theorem to reach that conclusion.

Comment: You don't "have to" accept any answer that fails to satisfy you, so feel free to un-accept and encourage others to answer. (One should usually allow a bit of time before accepting, anyway.) That said, you could/should make your desire clearer by asking up-front: *"How might we anticipate that $|AC|^2+|BC|^2=\text{constant}$ represents a circle?"*

Comment: Good pt, re clarifying my desire; it never occurred to me that an on-point geometric theorem would exist that didn't easily fulfill my underlying desire.  Re accept'g your answer, I feel compelled to for two reasons: (1) Your answer is **directly on-point** and can fulfill my underlying desire, though convoluted logic is involved. (2) Given the existence of Appollonius' (**triangle-oriented**) theorem, I strongly suspect that **there will not be a separate circle-oriented geometry theorem** that one might use.  Assuming that my suspicion is correct, then your answer is the best I'll get.

Comment: As to the logic being convoluted ... I don't think it *is*, necessarily. Symmetry requires that the center of the circle be the midpoint ($O$) of $AB$, so, "all we need" is a relation among $|AC|$, $|BC|$, $|OC|$, and, presumably, $|AB|$ (or half thereof). Stewart/Apollonius gives that relation, wherein the constancy of $|AC|^2+|BC|^2$ (and $|AB|$) immediately implies the constancy of $|OC|$. Done. That said, I'm actually inclined to believe that there's a more-satisfying diagrammatic demonstration of this fact.

Comment: I edited my query re your suggestion about clarifying my desire.  I agree with the logic of your latest comment.  My use of the adjective **convoluted** merely signifies that even if I had been aware of Appollonius' (**triangle oriented**) theorem, I could have **easily overlooked** that it can be used to show that the Locus is a circle.  Further, since the Locus **is** a circle, my initial intuition is that **some property of circles** must be involved.  This intuition is similar to the last sentence in your latest comment.