# Law of Cosines: Proof Without Words

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to prove the Law of Cosines using the following diagram taken from Thomas' Calculus 11th edition.

[image]

I have an answer, but I think there must be a simpler or better way to do it.  Here is my answer:

Construct a coordinate system such that $(0,0)$ is located at the bottom right corner of the pictured triangle.  Then the red line intersects the hypotenuse at $(-a,0)$ and a leg at $(-b\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$.  Thus the squared distance $c$ from $(-a,0)$ to $(-b\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$ is
\begin{align}
c^2&=(-b\cos\theta-(-a))^2 + (b\sin\theta)^2\\
&=a^2-2ab\cos\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta\\
&=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta.
\end{align}

I feel like there has to be a simpler way, since my proof is basically ignoring the right triangle, the circle, etc.  If somebody can show me another proof, that would be great.  Thanks.

**UPDATE:**  It looks like I needed the [Intersecting Chords Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem) from Geometry to write $(a+c)(a-c)=(2a\cos\theta-b)(b)$.

Comment: Using the formula $a\cdot b=|a|\cdot |b|\cdot \cos(\gamma)$ , where $\gamma$ is the angle between the vectors $a$ and $b$, we can establish a "one-line proof", if you prefer this approach.

Comment: Let $A$ be the vertex opposite $a$ in the $a$-$b$-$c$ triangle. Then express the [power of $A$ with respect to the circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) as two chord-chord products to get $$(2a\cos\theta-b)\cdot b = (a-c)\cdot(a+c)$$

Comment: @Blue That sounds like it ought to be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: You might find this a bit of fun: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304826271_A_proof_without_words_of_the_Law_of_Cosines

Comment: @ColinMcDonagh: That's a good one. It's not immediately obvious that the trapezoidal area pairs are equal, but it works. ... Despite searching, I've never found a dissection proof that didn't have such compromises and/or was robust across a wide range of triangles. Ultimately, I decide that [this trigonograph](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2483937/409) is about the best I could do. It's not a rigid dissection proof, but I like to think it has a certain charm.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The image was a little difficult for me to parse at first, so here's a refinement:

[image]

Now ... With $A$ the vertex opposite $a$ in the $a$-$b$-$c$ triangle, we can express [the power of $A$ with respect to the circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) as two chord-chord products to get

$$(2a\cos\theta-b)\cdot b = (a-c)\cdot(a+c)$$

and the result follows. $\square$

Comment: Excellent. Impossible not to vote for your answer.

Comment: Note that the right triangle is somewhat necessary in order to find the length $2a\cos\theta$ of the red chord.

Answer (score 1):

In the similar triangles, the ratio of corresponding sides are equal. We have $$
\begin{array}{l}
\dfrac{2 a \cos \theta-b}{a-c}=\dfrac{a+c}{b} \\
c^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}-2 a b\ cos \theta
\end{array}
$$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider triangle as vectors $ \overrightarrow{AC}=\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}$. Then we have $\overrightarrow{BC} = \overrightarrow{AC} -\overrightarrow{AB}$ and at last
$$\overrightarrow{BC^{2}} = \overrightarrow{AC^{2}} +\overrightarrow{AB^{2}}-2\cdot\overrightarrow{AC} \cdot \overrightarrow{AB} $$
Obtained equality written for length is Law of Cosines $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta$. It can proved, that condition $\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab} \in (-1,1)$ is necessary and sufficient for length $a,b,c$ to create triangle.

In Euclidean space there holds property, which can be considered as general form of cosines law
$$||x +y|| = ||x||^2+||y||^2+2(x,y)$$
where $(x,y)$ is scalar product.