# The formula of Pythagorean theorem for each area of tetrahedron.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, systems-of-equations, triangles, area

I should have depicted the following tetrahedron using tikz of tex. The image below is from [this instagram post](https://www.instagram.com/p/CgMVBm9jjKh/)

[image]

$$  \color{fuchsia}{\underbrace{S_4^2= S_1^2+S_2^2+S_3^2}_{\text{I want to derive this} } }  $$

$~ S_i ~$ represents the ith area of a triangle.

What I've done for deriving it are as follows.

$$\begin{cases}
(0,0,0) \leftarrow~~\text{coordinates where the 3 right angle symbols gather}\\ 
(a,0,0) \leftarrow~~\text{coordinates on x-axis}\\ 
(0,b,0) \leftarrow~~\text{coordinates on y-axis}\\ 
(0,0,c) \leftarrow~~\text{coordinates on z-axis}\\ 
\end{cases}$$

Please assume that x-axis is along with left and y-axis is along with right and z-axis with vertical.

$$\begin{cases}
S_1={1 \over 2 }bc\\
S_2={1 \over 2 }ac\\
S_3={1 \over 2 }ab\\
\end{cases}$$

So the remaining problem is to find out the formula of $~ S_4 ~$

What I've thought for it is to firstly find out the perpendicular line between $~ \text{AB}  ~$ and $~ \text{C}  ~$.

If that is done, then the coordinates on $~\text{AB}  ~$  which is passed by that perpendicular line is known(we define this position as $~ \text{D}  ~$ )

Hence

$$ S_4={1 \over 2 } \left( \text{AD} \cdot \text{CD} + \text{BD} \cdot \text{CD}   \right) $$

But this way seems a bit complicated one I think.

Is there some more simpler way to derive the area of $~ S_4 ~$ ?

In the first place I don't know how to find the perpendicular line...

Comment: A [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/563359/89922) has a link to a simple proof, that really relies on dropping perpendicular line from the origin to $AB$.

Comment: I am looking http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/pythagoras.shtml now which is on that post.

Comment: I think I derived the pink eqn. Since I am outside now, I will write an answer post later.

Comment: Sides of $S_4$ are $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, $e=\sqrt{a^2+c^2}$, $f=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$. Let altitude to $f$ is $h$, then $\sqrt{d^2-h^2}=f-\sqrt{e^2-h^2}$, $d^2-h^2=f^2-2f\sqrt{e^2-h^2}+e^2-h^2$, $2f\sqrt{e^2-h^2}=f^2+e^2-d^2$, $2\sqrt{f^2e^2-f^2h^2}=b^2+c^2+a^2+c^2-a^2-b^2=2c^2$, $f^2e^2-f^2h^2=b^4$, $f^2h^2=f^2e^2-c^4$, $f^2h^2=(b^2+c^2)(a^2+c^2)-c^4=a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2$. $S_4=fh/2$, then $S_4^2=S_1^2+S_2^2+S_3^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not necessary to derive an exact formula of a length of the perpendicular line. That is the key factor for proving the squared pink eqn.**

$$\begin{align}
p&:=\text{length of perpendicular line betwneen C and AB} \\
q&:=\text{length of line segment between the origin and AB} \\
d&:=\text{length of AB} \\
S_4^2&= \left({1 \over 2 }pd \right)^2\\&= {p^2 d^2 \over 4 }\iff 4S_4^2=p^2d^2\\
4S_4^2&=p^2d^2\\
&=d^2 \left(c^2+q^2 \right)\\
&=c^2d^2+d^2q^2\\
&=c^2 \left(a^2+b^2 \right)+d^2q^2\\
&=\cdots\\
&=4S_1^2+4S_2^2+4S_3^2\\
\therefore S_4^2&=S_1^2+S_2^2+S_3^2
\end{align}$$

BTW using tikz to depict a figure is very time taking for me so far.  But should I still use it? I wish I can use a tool which draw a figure with realtime response.