# Determinant as sum of cofactors

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have just gone through the proof that by summing the product of the elements and cofactors along any row of a matrix, you obtain the determinant.

I understand the mechanism of the proof, but could anyone explain this result in a more intuitive manner?

Comment: Do you want intuition for the determinant itself,or the computation using cofactors?

Comment: Might be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845196/geometric-interpretation-of-laplaces-formula-for-determinants

Comment: Intuition for the computation using cofactors