# Intuition of finding the formula of Laplace's expansions of the Determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, intuition, laplace-expansion

How did Laplace find the formula $\left |A  \right |=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+j}(A)_{ij}M_{ij}$? What is the intuition of the evalution of this formula?

Note: I'm not asking for proof that the formula is indeed a formula for the determinant, I'm asking about how does one evaluate and discovers a formula like this.

Another note: In the formula, $1\leq j\leq n$ is fixed. The minor $M_{ij}$ is the determinant of the $(n-1)*(n-1)$ matrix that results from $A$ by removing the i-th row and the j-th column.

Comment: Just one precision: what is $M$? And you should add the summation on $j$, too, please!

Comment: @Milloupe $M_{ij}$ is to be understood as a minor, thus no summation on $j$ !

Comment: @JeanMarie, sorry, English not being my native language, it wasn't obvious to me that M stood for minor, thank you!

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/845196 with a non-classical answer mentionning the important "Clifford algebra" vision.

Comment: @JeanMarie Well, that's one intuition, but I'm pretty sure Laplace did not know about Clifford algebras.

Comment: @Robert Israel I hadn't paid attention to the way the first sentence was written...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Laplace's actual steps, but the expansion follows from Cramer's Rule, which was known before Laplace.  Namely, if $A$ is a nonsingular $n \times n$ matrix the solution of the equation
$ A x = e_i$, where $e_i$ is the vector with $1$ in position $i$ and $0$ otherwise,  is $x_j = (-1)^{i+j} M_{ij}/\det(A)$.  Then the $i$'th entry of $A x = e_i$ gives you
$$ \sum_{j} a_{ij} x_j = \sum_{j} \frac{(-1)^{i+j} a_{ij} M_{ij}}{\det(A)} = 1 $$
Now solve for $\det(A)$.